# Laravel 5.7 redirected too many times when i use Lock Screen Traits

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, redirect

I'm trying to build Laravel Application, and I would like to add lock screen feature and I searched on google to see how it's work,

And I find this beautiful and simple Tutorial [GitHub:laravel-auth-lock-screen](https://github.com/Cannonb4ll/laravel-auth-lock-screen)

But it seems like there's something wrong in the code, Can someone help me, please!

**Error is**
After Session timeout the App redirects me to correct route 'login/locked' but the browser show localhost redirected you too many times. 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'

**route\web.php**

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('login/locked', 'Auth\LoginController@locked')->middleware('auth')->name('login.locked');
Route::post('login/locked', 'Auth\LoginController@unlock')->name('login.unlock');
```

**LoginController**

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{


    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except([
            'logout',
            'locked',
            'unlock'
        ]);
    }

    public function locked()
    {
        if(!session('lock-expires-at')){
            return redirect('/');
        }

        if(session('lock-expires-at') > now()){
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return view('auth.locked');
    }

    public function unlock(Request $request)
    {
        $check = Hash::check($request->input('password'), $request->user()->password);

        if(!$check){
            return redirect()->route('login.locked')->withErrors([
                'Your password does not match your profile.'
            ]);
        }

        session(['lock-expires-at' => now()->addMinutes($request->user()->getLockoutTime())]);

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

**Middleware**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AuthLock
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!$request->user()){
            return $next($request);
        }

        // If the user does not have this feature enabled, then just return next.
        if (!$request->user()->hasLockoutTime()) {
            // Check if previous session was set, if so, remove it because we don't need it here.
            if (session('lock-expires-at')) {
                session()->forget('lock-expires-at');
            }

            return $next($request);
        }

        if ($lockExpiresAt = session('lock-expires-at')) {
            if ($lockExpiresAt < now()) {
                return redirect()->route('login.locked');
            }
        }

        session(['lock-expires-at' => now()->addMinutes($request->user()->getLockoutTime())]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**User Model**

```
use LockableTrait;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you tell us what goes wrong? What is the result is now versus what the expected result should be?

Comment: I'm trying to show lockscreen if logged user if not active for few minutes, now i set the timeout value 1 minute to check but when i wait after 1 minute it redirect me to 'login/locked' route but browser shows 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'.

Comment: What I think is happening: `return redirect()->route('login.locked');` sends you to the route `login.locked` which sends you back to the `locked()` function in your `loginController` which redirects you back to `/`. Try instead of `/` another URL such as `/home` just to see what happens.

Comment: I tried to many solutions but still all routes is same issue i tried `dd()` tried `about(404)` i'm just trying to track the route only one thing fixing the ERR is to remove `return redirect()->route('login.locked');` in `if ($lockExpiresAt < now())` in Middleware file

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the problem in such way:
exclude `auth.lock` from :

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web'=>...
```

In **route\web.php** create Route group for all routes except **login\locked** and add your `auth.lock` middleware to this group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.lock']], function () {
    Route::get('/home', ['uses' => 'HomeController@index', 'as' => 'home']);
    ...
}
```

Comment: @daniel-marschall This solution works, but it only redirects when the page refreshes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** Guys I keep trying to fix the issue and i found that it's redirecting me to many times because I add the AuthLock Middleware in web group in Kernal Class

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'auth.lock'
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

now i searched for a long time how to apply middleware for all Application excepting the `login,login.locked and login.unlock` routes, any help please ?

Comment: No sorry I didn’t find any solution

Comment: Is any other way to solve this lockscreen issue if you have any helping material so i can implement this ?

Comment: Problem is only in middleware if we solve this then other all code working.

Comment: Yes the middleware is redirecting me to the lock screen and also the lock screen is redirecting me to url('/') and it's redirecting me again to the lockscreen because the session still locked, looks like we missing something i kept trying to much to fix it but i failed. i hope some perfect devoloper see this topic as soon as posibble

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude auth.lock from

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web'=>...
```